# React Native - How to set the environment variable REACT_DEBUGGER?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-debugger

I am unable to get [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging#debugging-using-a-custom-javascript-debugger) documentation for enabling the `REACT_DEBUGGER`. Where to find the path of the main file that will be executed for this `REACT_DEBUGGER`. Can anyone tell how to set it in windows environment?

Comment: In your case there's actually 2 possibilities. 1- operating system environment variables, 2- .env file of your react-app. Did you try each of them individually ?

Comment: no, because setting environment variable need path of the file, i dont know which file to add under `REACT_DEBUGGER`

Comment: the docs you linked says `node yourDebugger.js --etc` is interpreted as a run command in form of `node yourDebugger --etc /yourAppDir`. So, if you have `node.exe` in your PATH it should work just fine.